# Is it appropriate for me to ask questions about how to use BKChem in Ubuntu?

Tags: discussion

I've got the itch to set BKChem up such that it satisfies [these conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aManual_of_Style/Chemistry/Structure_drawing#Drawing_in_BKChem) imposed by Wikipedia on chemical structure drawing and I am using Ubuntu, but I don't know where my question would be best posed. Is there another StackExchange where I should ask this question or will Ask Ubuntu suffice?

Comment: I've seen you ask these types of questions before and they seemed to be well recieved, did something change?

Comment: I think that I have attempted to answer some of your questions in the past. I find them to be a refreshing change from the usual "Why is my screen black?". I usually end up learning something just from your questions. Why would they be a problem if they are Ubuntu related? As long as you are clear and concise about your work, I don't see a problem with them.

Answer (score 10):

Yeah, it should be on-topic here.

There may be a more appropriate site (is there one for BKChem and/or Wikipedia?) but failing that, Ask Ubuntu or Super User are fine alternatives.

---

Just reread what's going on. Given this is isn't just about using an application that existing in Ubuntu, it's about the platform-specific configuration locations, **this is definitely on topic**.